# SQL - How to match on string pattern starting at random index inside string

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have the following pattern;

> AA(AA)–NBXXYYY–CCCCCCC(CC)–DD(D)

Where the values in brackets are optional and may not exist.

I want to select only the XX part of the string. Could it be done with clever use of substring? I would appreciate any good input here.

Edit:
A hint might be that I can always skip the stuff before the first hyphen (-), which will always be there... but still not sure how to implement it.

Comment: I think you are on to something, the values would be something like this;

10-1R22345-33PY101-N4
100-1R22345-33PY101Z-N4
1000-1R22345-33PY101ZZ-N4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @S varchar(100) = 'AA(AA)-NBXXYYY-CCCCCCC(CC)-DD(D)'

-- First two characters after –NB
select substring(@S, charindex('-NB', @S)+3, 2)

-- Or if it is not always NB just find the first –
select substring(@S, charindex('-', @S)+3, 2)
```

With your sample data:

```
;with C(col) as
(
  select '10-1R22345-33PY101-N4' union all
  select '100-1R22345-33PY101Z-N4' union all
  select '1000-1R22345-33PY101ZZ-N4'
)

select substring(col, charindex('-', col)+3, 2)
from C
```

Comment: @cc0 - The second version requires that there are two characters between `–` and `XX`.

Comment: @cc0 You are using different kinds of hyphens. `select ascii('-'), ascii('–')` Thats why the second version seams buggy :). Try my update with your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method in C# to do the parsing otf the text field. Regardless what you do you are in a table scan area anyway - no index will work. So, if SQL limits you, just move on and use the integrated .NET runtime.

Comment: Tablescan is fine for my purpose, I am hoping to stay away from using CLR integration this time. Any clever ideas?